# Get all static instances of a method contained within itself

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a class that is set up like this:

```
public class Strategy
{
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly int Age;

    public Strategy(string Name, int Age)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Age = Age;
    }

    public static readonly Strategy CoolStrategy = new Strategy("Super Awesome", 24);
    public static readonly Strategy LameStrategy = new Strategy("Work Harder!", 14);
}
```

I want to be able to use an extension using reflection where I could say something like this:

```
Strategy[] CurrentStrategies = typeof(Strategy).GetStaticInstances<Strategy>();
```

And then as I add more static strategies within this class, this extension would return an array of them.  So in this case, it would return an array containing CoolStrategy and LameStrategy.

This would allow me to just add instances into the class and have places else where be able to get an array.

Any Ideas?

Comment: If you step through the loop (or at least as far as you can before the Exception) with the debugger, what are the FieldInfo objects' properties telling you?

Comment: Please be more clear with your question.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand your question, you want to get values of all public static fields of a given type. The following method does exactly that:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetStaticInstances<T>()
{
    Type typeOfInstance = typeof(T);

    IEnumerable<T> instances = typeOfInstance
        .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .Where(field => field.FieldType == typeOfInstance)
        .Select(field => (T)field.GetValue(null));

    return instances;
}
```

However, wouldn't it be sufficient to simply include a method in the `Strategy` class that would return all available strategies? If you'll want to add a new strategy in the future, you would simply add it to that method.

Comment: *However, wouldn't it be sufficient to simply include a method in the Strategy class that would return all available strategies?*

Why add a method that just duplicates a part of the metadata table? Also one can forget to add a new strategy, accidentally duplicate or delete rows etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're asking; but it sounds like you want to check the FieldInfo.FieldType instead of GetValue...

Comment: I already know the type of the field - it should be the same as the type parameter...

Comment: @william I clearly don't know what you're asking for then.  In your example code you're getting the value of the static fields of a given type, yet you're asking for a method named GetStaticFields<T> that doesn't have the exception--that's the only way to do what you've described so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class StrategyExtensions
{
    public static Strategy[] GetAllStrategies()
    {
        var statics = typeof (Strategy).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        var strategies = statics.Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof (Strategy));
        var values = strategies.Select(s => s.GetValue(null));
        return values.Cast<Strategy>().ToArray();
    }
}
```

then

```
var all = StrategyExtensions.GetAllStrategies();
foreach (var strategy in all)
    Console.WriteLine("name: {0} age: {1}", strategy.Name, strategy.Age);
```